# getting junk characters in firefox where as working fine in IE

Tags: firefox, character-encoding

I have used the below piece of code to get the output on the browser using printwriter.

```
String b= new String(a.getBytes("UTF-16LE"),"UTF-8");
```

The output is fine with IE but in firefox i get

> <�h�3�>�C�o�m�m�e�n�t�s�<�/�h�3�>� �<�t�a�b�l�e�>�<�t�r� �b�g�c�o�l�o�r�=�'�#�E�7�E�7�E�F�'�>�<�t�d�>�P�o�s�t�e�d� �O�n�:� �1�2�-�1�3�-�2�0�1�0� �1�0�:�3�8�:�2�4� �,� �B�y�:

This is the sample output of the problem facing.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">;
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
      CONTENT="no-cache">
  </head> 
  <body>
    <form name="form" method="post">
    <% 
    String theString = null; 
    PrintWriter pw = null; 
    String cmntbox = ""; 
    ServletOutputStream outStream = null; 
    try { 
      Connection con = null; 
      PreparedStatement pstmt = null; 
      ResultSet rs = null; 
      String sql = null; 
      InputStream sImage; 
      con = DBConnection.getConnection();
      sql = SELECT statement 
      pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); 
      while (rs.next()) { 
        byte bytearray[] = new byte[1048576]; 
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
        sImage = rs.getBinaryStream(1); 
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); 
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8"); 
        pw =response.getWriter(); 
        IOUtils.copy(sImage, writer); 
        theString = writer.toString(); 
        pw.write(theString); 
        pw.flush();
        cmntbox = Utility.getCommentPage(id,prcs_area); 
        String comment = new String(cmntbox.getBytes("UTF-16LE"),"UTF-8"); 
        pw.write(comment); 
        pw.flush(); 
        pw.close(); 
      }
```

Comment: Your `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" CONTENT="no-cache">` is invalid, and should be TWO `<meta>` tags. (And I doubt the code sample matches your actual code?)

Comment: TWO <meta> tags?? can i know how or where to put that arjan..

Comment: Simply `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` *and* `<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">` or `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">`. Not sure what is allowed in HTML 4 exactly.

Answer (score 2):

```
String comment = new String(cmntbox.getBytes("UTF-16LE"),"UTF-8");
```

is almost certainly wrong. The String that you get from `Utility.getCommentPage` should contain the characters you want. Converting those characters into bytes using one encoding, and then converting the bytes back into characters with another encoding, would result in what you're seeing.

In particular, every other byte in UTF-16 encoding for typical HTML is zero. And zero is a perfectly valid byte that encodes into a single NUL character in UTF-8. IE might be thinking, "Clearly this is wrong, so I will try to be helpful and do what I think you meant"; while Firefox is just showing what you said you wanted.

What happens if you skip the conversion and just do

```
pw.write(cmntbox);
```

directly? You already did the `response.setContentType` with the `charset=` before you did the `response.getWriter`. When you then `write` a String, it should do the character encoding for you.

Comment: skipping that conversion again i face encoding problems,even in IE there will be problems if i skip that conversion

Comment: hi ken,when i remove that conversion thing,the comment thing is working but pw.write(theString);  is giving junk ,this is the binary image which is then converted to string .

Comment: @pras, given your code sample: how could you be outputting both text *and* an image? You're telling the browser to expect HTML, right? Then what should a browser do when sending it an image and some text, rather than HTML? What does IE show you then?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that firefox doesn't know you are trying to display unicode. Have you tried putting in a proper doctype and content type?

The content type should be  < meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >

Similar issue - http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showpost.php?s=7981302b7ad7c59bb2b79ff03b462e45&p=680562&postcount=6

Comment: hey pulkit thanks for the response.But it is not working after using doctype also

Comment: what about content type meta tag? I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: i have used this 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" CONTENT="no-cache">

Comment: Could you paste the entire code in the question? That might help.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" CONTENT="no-cache">
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post">
<%
String theString = null;
PrintWriter pw = null;
String cmntbox = "";
ServletOutputStream outStream = null;
 try {
  Connection con = null;
  PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  String sql = null;
  InputStream sImage;

  con = DBConnection.getConnection();

Comment: sql = SELECT statement
  pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()) {
   byte bytearray[] = new byte[1048576];
   String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   sImage = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
   
  
   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
   
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
   pw =response.getWriter();
   
   IOUtils.copy(sImage, writer);
   theString = writer.toString();
   pw.write(theString);
   pw.flush();

Comment: cmntbox = Utility.getCommentPage(id,prcs_area);
    String comment = new String(cmntbox.getBytes("UTF-16LE"),"UTF-8");
    pw.write(comment);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
  }

Comment: hey am not able to format this code...are u able to understand ??

Comment: yes, I'll get back to you if I find something. Could you put this in the question itself?